# Chrome weird glitch while using Boostrap and Masonry.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, masonry

I've been working on website which has Bootstrap core, and when I included masonry for image layout (+using the Bootstrap grid) this bug occurs only on Chrome:

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oEwjkRszK0&feature=youtu.be)

But if I disable the masonry transition, everything is fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your effort

Comment: Do you mean posting the required code by that ?